# Mersenne numbers congruent to two

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that $2^{2^n-1} = 2 \pmod{2^n - 1}$ given that $2^n = 2 \pmod n$.

How would I go about proving that? I started by saying let $m = 2^n - 1$
Then, $2^n = 1 \pmod{m}$.

So I need to prove $2^m = 1 \pmod m$. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $2^n \equiv 1 \pmod{ 2^n-1} $.

Given that $2^n \equiv 2 \pmod{n}$, we know that $2^n - 1 \equiv 1 \pmod {n}$, or that $2^n -1 = kn + 1 $ for some integer $k$.

Thus, $2^{ 2^n -1 } = 2^{kn + 1} \equiv 2 \pmod{2^n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Write $2^n = 2 + a \cdot n$ with $a \ge 1$. Then $$2^{2^n - 1} = 2^{1 + an} = 2 + 2(2^{an} - 1) = 2 + (2^n - 1) \cdot [2 \cdot (2^{(a-1)n} + 2^{(a-2)n} + ... + 1)] \equiv 2 (\bmod 2^n - 1).$$